# Android read text from webpage

Tags: android

I've tried a lot of methods but didn't found anything working.
Can someone retrieve the "53.33" value from this web-page "https://www.iec.co.il/homeclients/pages/tariffs.aspx"?

I will really appreciate it if you can share me the code.

Thanks in advance,
Refael.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/%20%22Jsoup%22?)? It can fetch the HTML content of an URL and then process the contents, extract values, etc.